# Getting location of Views in Android in double format

Tags: android, android-layout

I am developing my own Custom Focus Manager for Android as there is a requirement.I need the X and Y coordinates of any view in Android.I am using :
getLocationOnScreen(arr); but this returns an Integer array.I need the coordinates to be in double so that when I do the calculations,it doesnt round off the values.Is there any way to get the X and Y coordinates in double ?

Comment: Multiply the value by 1.0 to convert to `double`.

Comment: You mean to say that i should multiply the value of X and Y coordinates returned by the  getLocationOnScreen by 1.0 ? But that would just convert integer to double for further calculations,but I wont be able to fetch double values of X and Y coordinates.Right ?

Comment: I guess it's impossible to get the value as `double`. AFAIK, position of `View` is rendered in pixel, which is in `int`. Same as width and height of rendered `View`; they're in pixel.